# Dreamweaver regex finding and replacing text inside xml tags?

Tags: xml, regex, tags, dreamweaver, replace

I have long xml file with various tags containing content related to a quiz. I need to find all the text inside the  tags and then remove the period at the end of the text answers.
How can I get this done easily using Dreamweaver's regex Find and Replace option?

My xml code example:

```
<Answer kind="Low">Two minutes or more.</Answer>
```

Thanks, Attila

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can assume that the period is always next to the `</` for the end tag, then you may be able to get away with just doing a "plain" replace to replace:

```
.</
```

with

```
</
```

However, if there can be whitespace between the period and the end tag, then doing a RegExp find and replace of:

```
\.(\s*)<\/
```

with

```
$1</
```

What this does is find a period followed by zero or more whitespace characters (capturing those whitespace characters) followed by